# Hiding nav menu based on Bootstrap breakpoint view

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am using Bootstrap template SB Admin (https://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin/) which has a hide/show side nav using a menu button on click. I want to retain the standard functionality on full screen which defaults to show the side nav unless specifically clicked to close.

On smaller screens/mobile the default behaviour is to hide the side nav unless clicked to open, which is fine however I want the nav to auto-close when clicking outside of the nav div - but only on mobile.

I can't work out how to trigger different behaviour based on breakpoints - any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the `dist` files or `src` files?

If you are using the `dist` files you can simply add this to your css, no extra jquery or js required.

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
   .sb-sidenav-toggled #sidebarToggle::before {
     content: '';
     position: fixed;
     display: block;
     z-index: 0;
     top: 0;
     left: 225px;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
   }
}
```

What this does is when the side nav is set to open, there is a class added to the body tag. `.sb-sidenav-toggled`.

We are also wrapping this using a css media query to make sure we are only on tablets/mobiles (991px below).

Then on the `#sidebarToggle` button (when open using this parent body class `.sb-sidenav-toggled`) is creating a fixed pseudo `::before` element (which is transparent) which covers the body area you want to be clickable to close side nav.

The magic is, because this pseudo element parent is the sidebar nav button, it means when it is clicked it triggers the standard close side nav event. And when it closes, the `.sb-sidenav-toggled` body class is removed, in turn removing the pseudo element.

---

If you are using `scss` files in the `src` folder, then you can use the sass below...

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
  #sidebarToggle {
    .sb-sidenav-toggled & {
      &:before {
        content: '';
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 0;
        display: block;
        top: 0;
        left: 225px;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great stuff, worked first time. Thank you for the explanation too, really helpful.